# Strategy for image viewer app in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Let say I want to create comic reader app where the user can download the comics as in app purchase, my question is should I go creating universal app or different app for iPhone and iPad ?
This app job is primarily just displaying image and my primary concern is about supplying the right size of images. My thought on this matter is:

Universal app:
Pro: Easier to deal with just one app rather than two
Con: The images must be in the iPad resolution (the biggest resolution), these images size is going to be wasted in iPhone who has smaller resolution.

Different iPad/iPhone app:
Pro: Can supply the right size for each platform
Con: User must purchase two separate app (and their in app purchase items) if they have both iPhone and iPad.

Since this is my first app I prefer to go with universal app so I don't have to maintain two different  apps but I welcome any input .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely go with the universal app.

I would think about the quantity and size of the images that you are going to pull. If not huge, you throw them in a frame and then dynamically size the frame/image depending on the device, you could support all different device ... here is a snip of code

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectZero;
imageRect.origin = imagePoint;
imageRect.size.width  = deviceSpecificImageWidth;
imageRect.size.height = deviceSpecificImageHeight;

[yourImage drawInRect:imageRect];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use (if you want to load the images in a imageView programmaticly)

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    // load ipad image

} else {    

    // load iphone image
}
```

Or you can make a universal app with the same classes only different xibs for iphone and ipad. But you will have to name you xibs: MyXib~iphone.xib and MyXib~ipad.xib and just link them to the same class ... the rest will be done automaticly

Comment: But i think the OP's concern is about having unnecessary images and not about how to load different images. I cant upvote this but won't downvote as its partially catering the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Toncean's suggestions are good. I would add that there is not as much resolution difference as you might think between iPad and iPhone.  The pad has a resolution of 1024x768. The iPhone 4 has a resolution of 960x640. So you are really not wasting much at all by using the same graphics for both.  You will of course want a set of lower res graphics for older iPhones. But that is something you'd have to do no matter which app option you chose.

Comment: I would go with a universal app, with one set of images for iphone4/ipad and one set for older iphones.

Comment: But isn't that more waste of space if I include lower res images for older iPhones along with larger res instead of just always using the largest images for all devices ?

Comment: Well it is recommended practice to include both.  Firstly, it helps you conserve space and graphics processing power on older devices.  In many cases you might be just fine with a single set of data but watch out for over taxing systems that are designed for lower res graphics.  Make sure that you test it on some older devices if you are going to go with only high res graphics.  No matter what, you will have to include an icon sized for each screen type.